# How do I create a Kibana visualization that shows the SUM of requests to each unique Filter value?

Tags: kibana, visualization, kibana-5

I'm trying to create a Kibana visualization that shows the number of requests per service.

Service is identified through a Filter called `Service_name`

I believe I can use SUM, however, each visualization either shows the total of all the requests to all the services, or I can Filter by a service.

How do I create a Visualization so that the x axis shows the `Service_name` value, and I have a sum of each service_name on the y axis?

Any help on this would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I'd like if you could give a few more details about this. If it has Lens Visualization, you can first use Count in the Y-axis and then use the Top Values option under the Horizontal Axis Configuration to select the 'Services_name' field.
If you're using an older version, you can use 'Terms aggregation' option that comes under the X-axis. 
Do let me know if this helps!